# Acquire random songs from Spotify API

Tags: api, spotify

I know how to query XX from Spotify API. As script below, we simply set `keywords = XX`

```
url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q='+ keywords +'&type=' + search_type +'&offset='+ off +'&limit=' + lim

j = requests.get(url).json()
```

But I'm wondering, what if I'd like to query for random songs, what shall I do? Simply query whitespace? Or generate random numbers for song ID?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently available in the Web API. If you're interested in submitting it as a feature request, you can do so here: http://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues

Answer (score 0):

in case you are willing to using python, we recently released an extension package for the spotipy API client that implements randomized search.

The package is named spotipy-random and can be found on [Github](https://github.com/michimalek/spotipy-random) and [pyPI](https://pypi.org/project/spotipy-random/).